# Excel VBA combine two Worksheet changes

Tags: excel, vba

Any chance you could help me combine these two worksheet changes?
I would like to enforce Uppercase letters for a range and prevent all copy/pasting.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim UndoList As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    On Error GoTo ErrExit
    UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
    If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Or UndoList = "Auto Fill" Then
        MsgBox "Copy / paste is not permitted" & vbCr & _
               "- Creator"
        With Application
            .Undo
            .CutCopyMode = False
        End With
        Target.Select
    End If

ErrExit:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Above is the prevent copy/past and below is the uppercase.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("AB26:QE124")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        With Target
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Let's go with the same range, as all other cells are locked.

Comment: So, the Target cell must be inside the  `Range("AB26:QE124")`. Is it corrrect?

Comment: Yeah that should cover it

Comment: So I will post an answer for not allowing copy/paste on all the sheet and make uppercase only the Target inside the above specified range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, keeping the condition to make UpperCase only for cells in `Range("AB26:QE124")` you can use the next merged code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UndoList As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    On Error GoTo ErrExit
    UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
    If left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Or UndoList = "Auto Fill" Then
        MsgBox "Copy / paste is not permitted" & vbCr & _
               "- Creator"
        With Application
            .Undo
            .CutCopyMode = False
        End With
        Target.Select
    End If

    'The UperCase part______________________________________________
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("AB26:QE124")) _
                                                    Is Nothing) Then
        With Target
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
    '_______________________________________________________________

ErrExit:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much FaneDuru!
I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer..

Comment: No problem! Glad to help you... Maybe when/if you will have more than 15, you will remember to come back and vote. Or not. Again, no problem... :-)